# Scanning all ports in my computer and identify printers on it

Tags: java, printing, port

In my application i need to have a feature to scan all the ports and list it for the user. Then the user will name the port with their custom names so that they can identify it easily. naming is not an issue in my case but my question is how to scan the ports and list it and how to use the port to print something on to the printer connected to the port.

I am using 3 USB printers connected to 3 USB ports. I have 6 USB ports available on my system so i need to list all the 6. For example let us say i have USB01, USB02,USB03, USB04,USB05,USB06. Now i will list this to the users and they name first three ports as Kitchen,bar,counter respectively. Now if i connect printers to those 3 ports i should be able to print on them at the same time.

If the question is not clear plz ask me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start with the [`PrintServiceLookup`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/print/PrintServiceLookup.html) class.

Comment: but this has got nothing to do with ports rite ? I have an implementation to scan and print on all available printers. but that is not i wanted. I need to identify the ports even before the printers are connected..

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to use a Java API related to USB ports, see
1. [IBM article about jUSB](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-usb/index.html#resources)
2. [javaUSB](http://jusb.sourceforge.net/apidoc/overview-summary.html)